# Como agregar referencia Google.Maps.LocationServices a mi proyecto ASp.Net

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, aplicación-web

Nesesito agregar esa referencia a mi proyecto pero no c como o que archivo descargar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías indicar en dónde quieres utilizar la API, si lado servidor o lado cliente. También si sabes porque se ha agregado la referencia. ¿Lo has hecho tu? ¿Estás siguiendo alguna guía o tutorial?

Comment: no estoy seguro si en el servidor o en el cliente ....yo no e agregado la referencia pero me da error al ejecutar y marca agregar referencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dale vía `nuget`, abre la `Package Manager Console` y ejecuta el siguiente comando:

```
Install-Package GoogleMaps.LocationServices
```

Comment: listo fino Gracias

Comment: Recuerda aceptar la respuesta que más te haya sido de utilidad para resolver tu pregunta, así mantenemos la buena salud del sitio :D